# password_verify works on Localhost but not in Virtual Host(webhost)

Tags: php

please help.

I have this simple script that verify password (argon 2):

```
$pass = password_verify($_POST['password_login'], $user[0]['pass']);
if ($pass != true) {
    $_SESSION['wrong_pass'] = true;
    header('Location: '.$path);
    exit();
}
```

This script always works on Xampp Localhost.
Otherwise, today I have upload the site on Umbler.com host, and I have tried hard but the password_verify always return false.

Works normally in localhost but not in the web host.
The localhost PHP version is 7.3.8, and the web host PHP version is 7.3.0.

Comment: Where does `$user[0]['pass']` come from? Have you compared that between your environments? Perhaps you're just submitting the wrong password?

Comment: just checked the changelog [manual](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#PHP_7_3) from 7.3.0 to 7.3.8, there's no changes or bugfix regarding `password_verify` so it should work as intended

Comment: try to explicitly use the argon 2 flag and try again

Comment: have you defined a static path for the localhost at development time globally ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem unfortunately was the host, I changed the webhost and everything works well. Thanks everyone for the answers.